# Mirrored part of the object is rotated

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

For some reason, when using the mirror modifier on a mesh, the mirrored part appears rotated. I'm not sure of why this is happening; I tried to change the pivot point, but it didn't seem to work.
Please, help would be extremely appreciated!

[image: A demonstration of how the object rotates. Red line indicating how it was supposed to mirror.]

Comment: Hi! The `Mirror Modifier` mirrors the part where the objects origin in, that orange dot in your image, so you would want to move the origin to where you have drawn that red line. As for why it's rotated we would need to see your settings. When supplying screen shots it's always best to include the whole Blender window so we can see what other settings you might have active, especially the modifiers.

Comment: Which axis are you trying to use when you mirror it? If you share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it, we'll be able to tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: This is perfectly mirrored.. across the wrong axis. The Object's axes are not aligned to its mesh, in the way you would prefer. Select all of your mesh, and rotate (about Z?) in Edit Mode. (You can display the Object axes in the 'Object' tab, 'Viewport Display' panel)

Comment: Your object is probably rotated and not aligned with the global axis any more, in object mode select your object and Ctrl A > Apply Rotation